# Pythonic way of applying a function to a chained list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to apply a function to a (chained) list and keep the structure in the most elegant way as possible. More precisely, consider

```
def fun(x, y):
    return x+y

list_1 = [[{'x': 3, 'y': 4}, {'x': 6, 'y': 5}], [{'x': 9, 'y': 4}, {'x': 1, 'y': 5}]]
list_2 = [{'x': 6, 'y': 4}, {'x': 5, 'y': 5}]
```

then the output for `list_1` should be `[[7, 11], [13, 6]]` and for `list_2` `[10, 10]`. This can be achieved using

```
[[foo(**i) for i in this_sublist] for this_sublist in list_1]
[foo(**i) for i in list_2]
```

However, I want to avoid to distinguish the different depths and rather have a single statement.

Comment: what you are after can be achieved with recursion and although with recursion you don't have to distinguish between the different cases, it would be more than a single statement..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recursive approach:

```
def operate(v):
    if isinstance(v, list):
        return [operate(v) for v in v]  # or list(map(operate, v))
    elif isinstance(v, dict):
        # use sum or whatever function you need on v
        return sum(v.values())
    # implement whatever error handling logic you want in case v is neither 
    # a dict nor a list


list_1 = [[{'x': 3, 'y': 4}, {'x': 6, 'y': 5}], [{'x': 9, 'y': 4}, {'x': 1, 'y': 5}]]
list_2 = [{'x': 6, 'y': 4}, {'x': 5, 'y': 5}]
list_3 = [[[{'x': 3, 'y': 4}, {'x': 6, 'y': 5}], [{'x': 9, 'y': 4}, {'x': 1, 'y': 5}]]]
print([operate(v) for v in list_1])
print([operate(v) for v in list_2])
print([operate(v) for v in list_3])
```

Outputs

```
[[7, 11], [13, 6]]
[10, 10]
[[[7, 11], [13, 6]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isinstance` to check if the type of the `obj`ect is a list:

```
def bar(l):
  return [[fun(**i) for i in obj] if isinstance(obj, list) else fun(**obj) for obj in l]

print(bar(list_1))
print(bar(list_2))
```

Output:

```
[[7, 11], [13, 6]]
[10, 10]
```

Comment: and what if its 3lvls deep?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Following the OP's example, there's only two levels of depth, but surely DeepSpace's recursive approach is better for a structure with a variable depth.